# access amazon s3 bucket without region end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I am accessing Amazon S3 using the Access key, Secret Access Key and region endpoint in Amazon S3 SDK which working fine.
 Like this

> client = new AmazonS3Client("some-access-key", "some-secret-key",Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)

Is it possible to remove region endpoint because Bucket name will be one globally so why we need region endpoint?

 
**There must be some way through which we can able to get region endpoint of the bucket in Amazon S3 SDK?? or can work without region endpoint if "Yes" then How ?? if "No" then Why??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bucket will always have a region, when leaving it blank it will create the bucket in the US East region for you. There can be several reasons for choosing a region, from the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html):

> By default, the bucket is created in the US East (N. Virginia) region. You can optionally specify a region in the request body. You might choose a region to optimize latency, minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements. For example, if you reside in Europe, you will probably find it advantageous to create buckets in the EU (Ireland) region.

While a bucket is always in a region, it is possible to have your data available in multiple regions using Cross-Region Replication. Which might help with what you n eed. See the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/) for details on how to set this up.